# Combine two different predicates in recursive SPARQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to extract the route-to-top lineage for all nodes in a biomedical ontology.  Sometimes the relationships are subClassOf, sometimes they're part_of (or maybe even something else.)

I was hoping to reflect all of these relationships in a single query, but I get a Virtuoso error:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SQ156: Internal Optimized compiler error : unknown table for a column dfe in sqldf.c:1451.
```

for the following query:

```
prefix bto: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix obo1: <http://data.bioontology.org/metadata/obo/>
select (group_concat(distinct ?midlab ; separator = "|") AS ?lineage)
where
{ 
  { bto:BTO_0000207 rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid } 
    UNION { bto:BTO_0000207 obo1:part_of* ?mid } .
  ?mid rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
  ?mid rdfs:label ?midlab .
}
group by ?lineage
order by (count(?mid) as ?ordercount)
```

I found this [bug report](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/159), but I can't tell if it's related:

Comment: To not address the question: The union can be replaced with "`bto:BTO_0000207 (rdfs:subClassOf*|bo1:part_of*) ?mid`"

Comment: @AndyS that works great if I make the query non-recursive by omitting the asterisks ( rdfs:subClassOf | obo1:part_of ), but if I try to keep it as a recursive query, I get the same error message

Comment: Quite possibly because it rewrites the syntax to the same internal form. Bug in engine. http://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/32281956/ (link to SF not working today).

Comment: Thanks, your logical OR suggestion works in Jena.  Make it an answer?